# Git: By default trying to use localhost as proxy

Tags: git, proxy

I got a problem recently, my git was trying to connect to localhost as proxy even I didn't set any proxy.

```
git.exe pull --progress --no-rebase -v "origin" #branch#

fatal: unable to access 'http://my/git/repo': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (1281 ms @ 15/2/2017 9:39:54 AM)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any environment variable with the work proxy in it:

```
env|grep -i proxy
```

Or at least set:

```
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,my
```

(with my being the domain you try to access to)

Comment: Got it.  You are right! somehow i found a proxy setting for http://127.0.0.1:98721...

Comment: @Chen That would make sense. Not sure where such a proxy setting would come from though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git config --global http.proxy xxxxxx:xxxx` to set proxy for git.
You can also use `git config --get http.proxy` to confirm your proxy configuration.

Comment: I did tried.  But I already made sure the proxies are blank.  Any more ideas?